# AwesomeFont - How to apply a mouse pointer cursor to a fa-icon

Tags: angular, font-awesome-4

How do you apply a mouse pointer / hover on a fa-icon?

I have the following Excel Icon - how can apply a mouse pointer when hovering over the icon?

I have tried the following. But does not work.

```
<fa-icon aria-hidden="true" class="ng-fa-icon file excel **fa-hand-pointer**" ng-reflect-ng-class="file-excel' ng-reflect-icon-prop="far, file excel">
 <svg  aria-hidden data-icon="file-excel....
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.fa-hand-pointer {
  /* Set the desired styles for the icon */
  cursor: pointer; /* Set the mouse pointer to a hand icon */
}

.fa-hand-pointer:hover {
  /* Set the desired styles for the hover effect */
  color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: I have to add a <style> ?  this not out of the 'box'?  thx  does the fa-icon have a hover property?